# grep in nested hash perl

Tags: perl, grep

My hash looks like this :

```
$VAR1 = {
      '1238' => {
                  'OUT3FA_5' => 65,
                  'SEV' => '3_major',
                  'OUT3A_5' => 20,
                  'OUT3-Fix' => 45,
                  'IN1' => 85
                },
      '1226' => {
                  'OUT3FA_5' => 30,
                  'SEV' => '4_minor',
                  'OUT3A_5' => 5,
                  'OUT3-Fix' => 25,
                  'IN1' => 40
                },
      '1239' => {
                  'OUT3FA_5' => 56,
                  'SEV' => '4_minor',
                  'OUT3A_5' => 34,
                  'OUT3-Fix' => 22,
                  'IN1' => 94
                }]
```

I want my Perl script to only return the values corresponding to "SEV" = "4_minor" In this case it'll return :

```
    '1226' => {
                  'OUT3FA_5' => 30,
                  'SEV' => '4_minor',
                  'OUT3A_5' => 5,
                  'OUT3-Fix' => 25,
                  'IN1' => 40
                },
      '1239' => {
                  'OUT3FA_5' => 56,
                  'SEV' => '4_minor',
                  'OUT3A_5' => 34,
                  'OUT3-Fix' => 22,
                  'IN1' => 94
                }
```

But when I use grep like this :

```
my $Sev_Logged = "4_minor";
my $node_hash = {
Week => [
  grep {  $hash{$_}{'SEV'} eq $Sev_Logged } %hash,
   ]
    };

# Print in json format
my $json = encode_json \%$node_hash;
print $json;
```

It only returns :

```
{"Week":["1226","1239"]}
```

And I want it to return all the other data corresponding to each of the weeks found containing SEV="4_minor".
How can I do this?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You've got an unmatched ] in your first code block.  Also, you're attempting to access a hash at the end of the grep line when you should be accessing a hashref which is what your first code block is. Try using something like 'keys %{$hash}' to get information from the hashref.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you hand a `%hash` over that way to `grep` then Perl interpretes the hash as an even-numbered list of keys and values -- resulting in the `grep {...}` block being called for once for each key and once for each value (instead of being called for each pair of key&value).

Try something like this:

```
{ map { ($_ => $hash{$_} } grep { $hash{$_}->{SEV} eq $Sev_Logged } keys %hash }
```

The `grep` keeps those hash keys for which the `SEV` field matches what you want. The `map` afterwards reconstructs a hash (because at that moment we only have the keys returned from `grep`), and finally we convert it to a hash reference.

Comment: Okay I see, I tried using map earlier but I guess I was doing it wrong, your solution works thank you!